# Parsing function that injects test cases to TestRail

Tags: python

This function has the purpose of injecting test cases into TestRail, it was written in bit of a hurry and I know there is room for improvement, any input will be appreciated.

```
def add_sections_and_test_cases(self, new_project_id, new_test_suite_id):
        """
        """
        new_sections_list = []
        new_section = None
        if self.parsed_json["folders"]:
            for folder in self.parsed_json["folders"]:
                arguments = {
                    "suite_id": new_test_suite_id,
                    "name": folder["name"],
                    "parent_id": ""
                }
                new_section = self.testrail_obj.send_post('add_section/%s/' % new_project_id, arguments)

                # add testcases to section = folders
                # loop through all testcases and see if they fit in this section
                custom_steps_list = []
                custom_steps_map = {}
                for folder in self.parsed_json["folders"]:
                    for order in folder["order"]:
                        for test_case in self.parsed_json["requests"]:
                            if order == test_case["id"]:
                                tmp_test_steps_list = []
                                tmp_test = None
                                for test in re.findall(r'tests\["[^]]+?\]', test_case["tests"]):
                                    if test != tmp_test:
                                       tmp_test_steps_list.append(test)
                                       tmp_test = test 

                                # loop through tmp list an create the final object
                                for test_step_text in tmp_test_steps_list:
                                    custom_steps_map = {
                                        "content": test_step_text,
                                        "expected": ""
                                    }
                                    custom_steps_list.append(custom_steps_map)

                                arguments = {
                                    "title": test_case["name"],
                                    "type_id": 3,
                                    "priority_id": 3,
                                    "estimate": "3m",
                                    # jira IDs
                                    "refs": "RF-1, RF-2",
                                    "custom_steps_separated": custom_steps_list
                                }
                                new_test_case = self.testrail_obj.send_post('add_case/%s/' % new_section["id"], arguments)
                                custom_steps_list = []
                                custom_steps_map = {}

        # test cases under no sections
        # tmp section will be created, test cases can not be inserted without section
        test_cases_with_no_section = False
        for test_case in self.parsed_json["requests"]:
            if not test_case["folder"]:
                test_cases_with_no_section = True
                break

        if test_cases_with_no_section:
            arguments = {
                "suite_id": new_test_suite_id,
                "name": "Test Cases tmp",
                "parent_id": ""
            }
            new_section = self.testrail_obj.send_post('add_section/%s/' % new_project_id, arguments)

            custom_steps_list = []
            custom_steps_map = {}
            # loop through requests and where folder=null, insert those test cases
            for test_case in self.parsed_json["requests"]:
                if not test_case["folder"]:
                    tmp_test_steps_list = []
                    tmp_test = None
                    for test in re.findall(r'tests\["[^]]+?\]', test_case["tests"]):
                        if test != tmp_test:
                           tmp_test_steps_list.append(test)
                           tmp_test = test 

                    # loop through tmp list an create the final object
                    for test_step_text in tmp_test_steps_list:
                        custom_steps_map = {
                            "content": test_step_text,
                            "expected": ""
                        }
                        custom_steps_list.append(custom_steps_map)

                    arguments = {
                        "title": test_case["name"],
                        "type_id": 3,
                        "priority_id": 3,
                        "estimate": "3m",
                        # jira IDs
                        "refs": "RF-1, RF-2",
                        "custom_steps_separated": custom_steps_list
                    }

                    new_test_case = self.testrail_obj.send_post('add_case/%s/' % new_section["id"], arguments)                     
                    custom_steps_list = []
                    custom_steps_map = {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Give functions some love!
   You can make *at least* two functions for this code: `remove_consecutive_duplicates` and `create_test`.
   They also can make your code much easier to read,
   and prevent you from repeating yourself.
2. You can reduce the amount of tabs there are in your program.

   Currently you have:

   ```
   for folder in self.parsed_json["folders"]:
       for order in folder["order"]:
           for test_case in self.parsed_json["requests"]:
               if order == test_case["id"]:
                   # More code
   ```

   Instead use a generator comprehension:

   ```
   order_tests = (
       test_case
       for folder in self.parsed_json["folders"]
       for order in folder["order"]
       for test_case in self.parsed_json["requests"]
       if order == test_case["id"]
   )

   for test_case in order_tests:
       # More code
   ```

   Oh no it's a few more lines for *a lot less tabs*.
   This makes reading code easier as now you don't have to horizontal scroll to read anything.
3. Really give comprehensions some love!

   I got your code to 64 Pythonic lines of code compared to your 99.

   For example the `create_test` function could be:

   ```
   def create_test(self, new_section, test_case):
       arguments = {
           "title": test_case["name"],
           "type_id": 3,
           "priority_id": 3,
           "estimate": "3m",
           "refs": "RF-1, RF-2",
           "custom_steps_separated": [
               {
                   "content": test_step_text,
                   "expected": ""
               }
               for test_step_text in remove_consecutive_duplicates(re.findall(r'tests\["[^]]+?\]', test_case["tests"]))
           ]
       }
       self.testrail_obj.send_post('add_case/%s/' % new_section["id"], arguments)
   ```

   This is *so much easier* to read and understand then your odd and awkward `custom_steps_list`.
   No more where do I define `custom_steps_list` to an empty array.

---

I made `remove_consecutive_duplicates` a proper generator, as you can't make it a comprehension.
And reduced `add_sections_and_test_cases` to use as few indents as possible whilst still being easy to read and understand.
The biggest change I made, apart from the ones above, is filtering out `if not test_case["folder"]` to reduce the amount of code.

```
def remove_consecutive_duplicates(iterable):
    last = None
    for i in iterable:
        if i != last:
            yield i
            last = i


def create_test(self, new_section, test_case):
    arguments = {
        "title": test_case["name"],
        "type_id": 3,
        "priority_id": 3,
        "estimate": "3m",
        "refs": "RF-1, RF-2",
        "custom_steps_separated": [
            {
                "content": test_step_text,
                "expected": ""
            }
            for test_step_text in remove_consecutive_duplicates(re.findall(r'tests\["[^]]+?\]', test_case["tests"]))
        ]
    }
    self.testrail_obj.send_post('add_case/%s/' % new_section["id"], arguments)


def add_sections(self, new_project_id, new_test_suite_id):
    if self.parsed_json["folders"]:
        for folder in self.parsed_json["folders"]:
            arguments = {
                "suite_id": new_test_suite_id,
                "name": folder["name"],
                "parent_id": ""
            }
            new_section = self.testrail_obj.send_post('add_section/%s/' % new_project_id, arguments)
            for test_case in (
                    test_case
                    for folder in self.parsed_json["folders"]
                    for order in folder["order"]
                    for test_case in self.parsed_json["requests"]
                    if order == test_case["id"]):
                self.create_test(new_section, test_case)


def add_test_cases(self, new_project_id, new_test_suite_id):
    test_cases = [
        test_case
        for test_case in self.parsed_json["requests"]
        if not test_case["folder"]
    ]
    if test_cases:
        arguments = {
            "suite_id": new_test_suite_id,
            "name": "Test Cases tmp",
            "parent_id": ""
        }
        new_section = self.testrail_obj.send_post('add_section/%s/' % new_project_id, arguments)
        for test_case in test_cases:
            self.create_test(new_section, test_case)


def add_sections_and_test_cases(self, new_project_id, new_test_suite_id):
    self.add_sections(new_project_id, new_test_suite_id)
    self.add_test_cases(new_project_id, new_test_suite_id)
```